# How to get the facebook profile pic url

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get the facebook profilePic url. with facebook graph below given facebook profile getting downloaded in the browser but not showing in the browser. I just need like image url({path}.png or jpg).

https://graph.facebook.com/101593087796313/picture?type=square (downloading the image)

I need to get the image url.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Thanks,
Syamala.

Comment: It downloads the image, if you click directly on a link like above. Put it into the `src` attribute of an `img` element, then it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/jfart459/

Comment: @04FS it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/user/picture

Set the `redirect` parameter to `false` if you just want to get the url as JSON.

Comment: Thanks @luschn . That, I have tried!

    `https://graph.facebook.com/101593087796313/picture?type=square&redirect=false (it returns json reponse)`


    response
    --------
  ` {
   "data": {
      "height": 50,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=101593087796313&height=50&width=50&ext=1563734365&hash=AeSC0Tv4pDcyJJNJ",
      "width": 50
   }
}`


the url field from the above response is the image, again it is an image, not an image url(not .jpeg).

Comment: It is an image URL that if you request it will give you the image

Comment: it is getting download the image, not showing the image in the browser when we hit.

Comment: it is possible? same problem here, no solution.